# How to create a new Mercurial branch using Netbeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, branch

Is it possible to create a new branch using Netbeans? and how could switch between branches?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, at least not with the default plugin. Creating and switching between branches is really easy in CLI, is there a reason you want to do it in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old but netbeans 7.1 has this ability now.